# Using Motor Encoder with M8706

Tags: motor, encoder

I am working on extracting encoder data from a dc motor (apparently a "Pitman"). The encoder is somewhere inside the casing and the only interface it has with the outside is through a 4 pin connector on a piece of circuit outside. There is an IC reading M8706 on the circuit. Now, I cant find anything about this IC and thus am helpless in getting any idea about the wires; where to connect Ground and Power for the Encoder and from where to get the encoder data.

Comment: Do you have a photo of the motor and the wires? A common wiring I have seen is for the Red to be the +ve of the LED and the Black the -ve, the transistor to be the other wires (one yellow one blue?)

Comment: Actually there is white bus having 4 wires so its not possible to identify the respective wires based on the colors.
P.S photos i cant upload since i dont carry much reputation apparently..

Comment: Try measuring the voltage drop across pairs of wires using the diode setting. Also a link to a public web site you can uplaod to.. someone will include the picture for you.

Comment: @UmerHuzaifa  Upload the photo to some 3rd party image hosting site on the web (e.g. flicker, picasa, etc), then edit your post and add a link to that photo.  Somebody with enough reputation will edit your post and inline the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Pittman (two "t"s) motor has an encoder, it seems likely it's one of the ones in the encoder section of their catalog, or similar to one in there.  http://www.pittman-motors.com/Portals/0/DC_Motor_Catalog/Incremental_Encoders.pdf

Comment: Thanks guys.
I found out that normally, 
a complete bed of Copper trace is for the GND terminal..
then there is the Power terminal at next to next pin..
the other two pins give the encoder output. any of these can be used..